# In browser inspect element html code show in encrypted form or hide code

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, security, encryption

I have make new HTML template and Admin panel. I want no one see my HTML. If HTML show in browser inspect element in encrypted format and no one able to download my HTML code by browser.

My website in Laravel + HTML5.

Comment: It's not possible. HTML is the skeleton of webpage. So they'll show in client's browser anyway. But you can somehow encrypt they JavaScript code, though I don't know how, a quick googling will help!

Comment: This cannot be done in a safe way. If the browser is able to display the page, someone determined to get your code will be able to do so as well. You can still [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) your code as much as possible, but really, there's **no way** to hide it entirely. Not even using javascript.